# Mobx observable and componentDidUpdate() not behaving as expected when passing props [Typescript React]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I'm using react + mobx + typescript and want to send a json array from my logic layer to a UI component. The json comes from an async api call. I"m saving it in a mobx @observable variable and sending it as props to my UI component. I'm relying on `componentDidUpdate()` in my UI to detect when changes happen, since it's coming from an api call. Things aren't working as expected.

Here's a trimmed version of my logic component:

```
@observer
class DeadletterLogic extends Component<Props, State> {

    @observable queues: any[];
    @observable deadletterQueues: any[];
    @observable temp: any;

    private service: DeadletterService;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        // create new service object
        this.service = new DeadletterService();
        this.returnDeadletterInfo(this.service);

    }

    async returnDeadletterInfo(service: DeadletterService) {  
        await this.getQueues(this.service); // get all queues from the service layer
        await this.getDeadletters(this.service);
    }

     async getQueues(service: DeadletterService) {
        // in order to gets a list of queues here, a fetch call must be made in the service layer to the MessageQueueAPI

        let queues = await service.getQueues(); // gets a json array of all the queues

        this.queues = queues.map(data =>
                 data.id
        );

    }

    async getDeadletters(service: DeadletterService) {

        this.deadletterQueues = []; // initialize the array
        let queues = this.queues;

        for (var i = 0; i < queues.length; i++) {
            let queueToGet = queues[i]; // gets current queue name
            let deadletters = await service.getByQueue(queueToGet); // gets the json object with this name from service layer
            this.deadletterQueues.push(deadletters); // pushes that object onto the array
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Deadletters deadletterQueues={this.deadletterQueues}/>         
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And here's a trimmed version of my UI:

```
    deadletterQueues: any[];
}

interface State {
    loading: boolean
}

@observer
class Deadletters extends Component<Props, State> {

    @observable oneDeadletter: any;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { loading: true };
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.deadletterQueues !== prevProps.deadletterQueues) {
            // here is where I would map the information I need, but this is only hit once
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.oneDeadletter}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The issue is that componentDidUpdate is only triggering once, so the intial prop value (of nothing) is all I can get from `props.deadletterQueues` in the child component. I'd like componentDidUpdate to hit whenever the @observable array is pushed to (or modified) in the parent component so that I can extract data from it in the UI.

Even more confusing, I do get my desired functionality of the prop updating in the child component if I change my logic layer to something like:

```
    this.temp = deadletters.map(data =>
        data.messageId);
    this.deadletterQueues.push(this.temp); // pushes that object onto the array
```

and push `this.temp` as props instead. However, I need to be able to map from the UI, so this doesn't work for me. I'm struggling to see why one of these actions causes `componentDidUpdate` to trigger when the @observable in the parent changes and the other does not.

Any enlightment on this would be very much appreciated. I believe it's a mobx thing and has to do with pushing values to an array not being recognized as a change, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to insert one line in `render` function.

```
    render() {
        const { deadletterQueues } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {this.oneDeadletter}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

In fact, I don't know the reason.

It is much similar to my case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797827/update-chart-with-mobx-store).

I will update my answer when I find the reason. :)

**EDIT**: I found the reason:

> `MobX` only tracks data accessed for observer components if they are directly accessed by `render`

For more details: check these below

[here](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html#mobx-only-tracks-data-accessed-for-observer-components-if-they-are-directly-accessed-by-render)   and          [here](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html#avoid-caching-observables-in-local-fields)

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar issue. I suggest anyone who runs in this situation use the "autorun" or "reaction" functions of mobx.

Autorun will run every time a specific observable changes. For example, if we wanted to print the value of the counter every time it changes, we could do like this:

```
autorun(() => {
    console.log(`Counter changed to: ${this.counter}`)
```

})

Reaction is very similar to autorun, but it gives you more control over which observables’ values should be tracked. It receives two arguments: the first one is a simple function to return the data to be used in the second argument. The second argument will be the effect function; this effect function will only react to data that was passed in the first function argument. This effect function will only be triggered when the data that you passed in the first argument has changed.

```
reaction(() => data, (data, reaction) => { sideEffect }, options?)
```

JavaScript
For example, let’s create a reaction to print in the console when the counter it’s greater than 100.

```
const customReactionCounter = reaction(
    () => counter.length > 100,
    counter => console.log(`Counter is: ${counter}`)
)
```

Please check this page for further explanation and examples: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/guide-to-mobx

So instead of trying to compare the values of props in "componentDidUpdate", you can just use autorun and it will detect the change. Or you can specifically check if the value of a certain observable is changed with "reaction"