# Rerender component as mobx store is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I am using `chart.js` to show price changes from the `backend` in real time.
`Backend` sends a new price when it is changed to `frontend`.
`priceData`(array) is saved in `mobx` `priceChartStore`.
I have to update `chart` as price is changed.
I use `ref` value of `canvas` tag to draw price chart.

**The problem** is that the `componentDidUpdate` function is not called unless I call that `priceData`value in `render` function,even though It isn't used in `render` function.

*It works:*

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  const { priceChartStore: { priceData } = this.props;
...
// update chart
  this.chart = new LineChart({
      el: this.el,
      priceData,
      config: {
      liveMode: true,
      startTime,
      endTime,
      maxDataLength: MAX_PRICES_LENGTH,
      },
  });
...
}
// render function
render() {
    const {
        priceChartStore: { priceData }, // never used in render function
    } = this.props;
    return (
        <ChartCanvasWrapper>
            <canvas ref={el => (this.el = el)} />
        </ChartCanvasWrapper>
    );
}
```

*it doesn't work:*

```
// render function
render() {
    // const {
    //     priceChartStore: { priceData }, // never used in render function
    // } = this.props;
    return (
        <ChartCanvasWrapper>
            <canvas ref={el => (this.el = el)} />
        </ChartCanvasWrapper>
    );
}
```

Is this the way `mobx` works or is it my fault?

Note: I am sure that there's no bug or issue in `priceChartStore` and injecting it to this `component`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way `mobx` works in react (with [react-mobx)](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#observercomponentclass)

> React component class or stand-alone render function into a reactive component, which tracks which observables **are used by render** and automatically re-renders the component when one of these values changes.

So `mobx` will tracks only the `variables` used in the `render` function and cause re-render when they change.